# PHP check if array contains all positions

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array of arrays:
Ex:

```
array(
     array([name]=>AAA
           [size]=>300x250
           [count]=>10
          )
     array([name]=>AAA
           [size]=>160x600
           [count]=>9
          )
     array([name]=>AAA
           [size]=>728x90
           [count]=>3
          )
     array([name]=>CC
           [size]=>300x250
           [count]=>66
          )
     array([name]=>CC
           [size]=>160x600
           [count]=>55
          )
     array([name]=>DD
           [size]=>728x90
           [count]=>100
          )          
)
```

I have this array:

```
array("300x250", "160x600", "728x90", "300x600", "300x300", "120x600", "100x72", "970x250", "750x200", "120x60", "200x600");
```

I need to check if each 'name' contains all sizes of this last array, if doesn't exist I need to add.
The expect result is the 'name' AAA be repeated 11 times, the same for 'name CC' 'DD' and so one, with all sizes of the last array.

I tried make 2 for each to compare , but couldn’t distinct from 'name' AA and the others
Also I have the field count. So i need to keep the initial 'count' and every time I add a missing position I need to make the 'count' value of the new position = 0

Can someone help me how to check it?
My actual code

```
  $tmp22222=array();
        foreach ($result as &$v){
            foreach ($sizes as $s) {
                if($v['size']==$s) {
                    array_push($tmp22222, $v);
                break;
                }
                if(!in_array($tmp22222, $v['size'])){
                    $v['size'] = $s;
                    $v['count'] = 0;
                    array_push($tmp22222, $v);
                }

            }
        }


    var_dump($tmp22222);
```

EXCPECTED RESULT:

```
array(
     array([name]=>AAA
           [size]=>300x250
           [count]=>10
          )
     array([name]=>AAA
           [size]=>160x600
           [count]=>9
          )
     array([name]=>AAA
           [size]=>728x90
           [count]=>3
          )
     array([name]=>AAA
           [size]=>300x600
           [count]=>0
          )
     array([name]=>AAA
           [size]=>300x300
           [count]=>0
          )
     array([name]=>AAA
           [size]=>120x600
           [count]=>0
          )
     array([name]=>AAA
           [size]=>100x72
           [count]=>0
          )
     array([name]=>AAA
           [size]=>970x250
           [count]=>0
          )
     array([name]=>AAA
           [size]=>750x200
           [count]=>0
          )
     array([name]=>AAA
           [size]=>120x60
           [count]=>0
          )
     array([name]=>AAA
           [size]=>200x600
           [count]=>0
          )

     array([name]=>CC
           [size]=>300x250
           [count]=>66
          )
     array([name]=>CC
           [size]=>160x600
           [count]=>55
          )
     array([name]=>CC
           [size]=>728x90
           [count]=>100
          )
     array([name]=>CC
           [size]=>300x600
           [count]=>0
          )
     array([name]=>CC
           [size]=>300x300
           [count]=>0
          )
     array([name]=>CC
           [size]=>120x600
           [count]=>0
          )
     array([name]=>CC
           [size]=>100x72
           [count]=>0
          )
     array([name]=>CC
           [size]=>970x250
           [count]=>0
          )
     array([name]=>CC
           [size]=>750x200
           [count]=>0
          )
     array([name]=>CC
           [size]=>120x60
           [count]=>0
          )
     array([name]=>CC
           [size]=>200x600
           [count]=>0
          )
```

All positions with 'count'=0 were added 
As you can see, the existing sizes and count on first array continue with same values, just adding the new sizes with count=0

Comment: show us your code :)

Comment: hi @HalayemAnis I added my code, thanks

Comment: *"if doesn't exist I need to add"* – add what to what?

Comment: Sorry. AA only have 3 sizes from the other array. I must add AA with the missing sizes and count=0

Comment: Is `AAA`, `CC` etc. fixed? Or will you have to look at the first array to figure out the names you need to worry about? In other words, will the result always contain `AAA`, `CC` and `DD`, or can there be more names, or different names, or maybe not all three?

Comment: No that names are just an example. I never know the names. I added the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below simple solution:

```
    $array = array(
        array('name' => 'AAA',
            'size' => '300x250',
            'count' => '10',
        ),
        array('name' => 'AAA',
            'size' => '160x600',
            'count' => '9',
        ),
        array('name' => 'AAA',
            'size' => '728x90',
            'count' => '7',
        ),
        array('name' => 'CC',
            'size' => '300x250',
            'count' => '5',
        ),
        array('name' => 'CC',
            'size' => '160x600',
            'count' => '7',
        ),
        array('name' => 'DD',
            'size' => '728x90',
            'count' => '1',
        )
    );

    $size_array = array("300x250", "160x600", "728x90", "300x600", "300x300", "120x600", "100x72", "970x250", "750x200", "120x60", "200x600");

    //get unique name from original array
    $names = array_unique(array_column($array, 'name'));
    /**
 * for php < 5.5 change above line to
 *
   $names = array_map(function($element) {
     return $element['name'];
    }, $array);
    $names = array_unique($names);
 */
    foreach($names as $name){
        $size_exists_array = array_filter($array, function($val) use($name){
                if($val['name'] == $name){
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
        });

        //get already exists size
        $size = array_unique(array_column($size_exists_array, 'size'));
        /**
     * for php < 5.5 change above line to
     *
       $size = array_map(function($element) {
        return $element['size'];
      }, $size_exists_array);
      $size = array_unique($size);
     */
        //calculate difference of exist and available size
        $diff = array_diff($size_array, $size);

        //insert non exists size for name
        if($diff){
            foreach($diff as $dif){
                $array[] = array('name' => $name, 'size' => $dif, 'count' => '0',);
            }
        }
    }
    sort($array);

    print_r($array);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => AAA
            [size] => 100x72
            [count] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => AAA
            [size] => 120x60
            [count] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => AAA
            [size] => 120x600
            [count] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => AAA
            [size] => 160x600
            [count] => 9
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => AAA
            [size] => 200x600
            [count] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => AAA
            [size] => 300x250
            [count] => 10
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [name] => AAA
            [size] => 300x300
            [count] => 0
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [name] => AAA
            [size] => 300x600
            [count] => 0
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [name] => AAA
            [size] => 728x90
            [count] => 7
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [name] => AAA
            [size] => 750x200
            [count] => 0
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [name] => AAA
            [size] => 970x250
            [count] => 0
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [name] => CC
            [size] => 100x72
            [count] => 0
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [name] => CC
            [size] => 120x60
            [count] => 0
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [name] => CC
            [size] => 120x600
            [count] => 0
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [name] => CC
            [size] => 160x600
            [count] => 7
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [name] => CC
            [size] => 200x600
            [count] => 0
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [name] => CC
            [size] => 300x250
            [count] => 5
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [name] => CC
            [size] => 300x300
            [count] => 0
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [name] => CC
            [size] => 300x600
            [count] => 0
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [name] => CC
            [size] => 728x90
            [count] => 0
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [name] => CC
            [size] => 750x200
            [count] => 0
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [name] => CC
            [size] => 970x250
            [count] => 0
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [name] => DD
            [size] => 100x72
            [count] => 0
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [name] => DD
            [size] => 120x60
            [count] => 0
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [name] => DD
            [size] => 120x600
            [count] => 0
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [name] => DD
            [size] => 160x600
            [count] => 0
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [name] => DD
            [size] => 200x600
            [count] => 0
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [name] => DD
            [size] => 300x250
            [count] => 0
        )

    [28] => Array
        (
            [name] => DD
            [size] => 300x300
            [count] => 0
        )

    [29] => Array
        (
            [name] => DD
            [size] => 300x600
            [count] => 0
        )

    [30] => Array
        (
            [name] => DD
            [size] => 728x90
            [count] => 1
        )

    [31] => Array
        (
            [name] => DD
            [size] => 750x200
            [count] => 0
        )

    [32] => Array
        (
            [name] => DD
            [size] => 970x250
            [count] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: i don't know why, $val['name']==$name is empty

Comment: So doesn't display anything

Comment: which version of php you are using

Comment: php 5.6, I did  var_dump($val['code']); and check that it doesn't get anything

Comment: Sorry, on server I have  5.3.10

Comment: Could you just explain me this part:  $size_exists_array = array_filter($result, function($val) use($name){
            if($val['code'] == $name){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });

Comment: its returning the array which contains all size for specific name from original array.. just try with `print_r($size_existing_array)`

Answer (score 2):

It becomes simpler if you change your array format:

```
// reformat array into ['AAA' => ['300x250' => 10, ..]]
$grouped = array_reduce($result, function (array $grouped, array $item) {
    $grouped[$item['name']][$item['size']] = $item['count'];
    return $grouped;
}, array());

// create default size => 0 mapping
$defaultSizes = array_fill_keys($sizes, 0);

// add default size => 0 map to each name group, doesn't overwrite existing values
$grouped = array_map(function (array $group) use ($defaultSizes) {
    return $group + $defaultSizes;
}, $grouped);

// reformat into original structure
$result = array_reduce(array_keys($grouped), function (array $result, array $name) use ($grouped) {
    foreach ($grouped[$name] as $size => $count) {
        $result[] = compact('name', 'size', 'count');
    }
    return $result;
}, array());
```

Comment: Is gives me an unexpected '['  on first function. here:  $grouped[$result['name']][$result['size']] = $result['count'];
    return $grouped;
}, []);

Comment: Are you perhaps running a pretty old PHP version? `[]` (just `[]` by itself, not as in `$grouped[]`) is the shorthand notation for `array()` in PHP 5.4+. If you're using something older: 1) upgrade, 2) replace the `[]` array literals with the old `array()`.

Comment: So replace the last argument `[]` for both `array_reduce` with `array()` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It is not efficient way but it has a lot of combination.

```
 $sizes = array("300x250", "160x600", "728x90", "300x600", "300x300", "120x600", "100x72", "970x250", "750x200", "120x60", "200x600");
$ex = array(
     array("name"=>"AAA",
           "size"=>"300x250",
           "count"=>10
          ),
     array("name"=>"AAA",
           "size"=>"160x600",
           "count"=>9
          ),
     array("name"=>"AAA",
           "size"=>"728x90",
           "count"=>3
          ),
     array("name"=>"CC",
           "size"=>"300x250",
           "count"=>66
          ),
     array("name"=>"CC",
           "size"=>"160x600",
           "count"=>55
          ),
     array("name"=>"DD",
           "size"=>"728x90",
           "count"=>100
          )          
);

$reorderedEx = array();

foreach($ex as $item){
  $reorderedEx[$item["name"]][$item["size"]] = $item["count"];
}
foreach($sizes as $size){
  foreach($reorderedEx as $name=>$r){
        if(empty($reorderedEx[$name][$size])){
            $reorderedEx[$name][$size] = "0";
        }
  }
}
$reconstruct = array();
foreach($reorderedEx as $name => $val){
    foreach($val as $size => $count){
        $reconstruct[] = array("name" => $name,"size"=>$size,"count"=>$count);
    } 

}

echo "<pre>",print_r($reconstruct,true);
```

Result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => AAA
            [size] => 300x250
            [count] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => AAA
            [size] => 160x600
            [count] => 9
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => AAA
            [size] => 728x90
            [count] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => AAA
            [size] => 300x600
            [count] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => AAA
            [size] => 300x300
            [count] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => AAA
            [size] => 120x600
            [count] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [name] => AAA
            [size] => 100x72
            [count] => 0
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [name] => AAA
            [size] => 970x250
            [count] => 0
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [name] => AAA
            [size] => 750x200
            [count] => 0
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [name] => AAA
            [size] => 120x60
            [count] => 0
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [name] => AAA
            [size] => 200x600
            [count] => 0
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [name] => CC
            [size] => 300x250
            [count] => 66
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [name] => CC
            [size] => 160x600
            [count] => 55
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [name] => CC
            [size] => 728x90
            [count] => 0
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [name] => CC
            [size] => 300x600
            [count] => 0
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [name] => CC
            [size] => 300x300
            [count] => 0
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [name] => CC
            [size] => 120x600
            [count] => 0
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [name] => CC
            [size] => 100x72
            [count] => 0
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [name] => CC
            [size] => 970x250
            [count] => 0
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [name] => CC
            [size] => 750x200
            [count] => 0
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [name] => CC
            [size] => 120x60
            [count] => 0
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [name] => CC
            [size] => 200x600
            [count] => 0
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [name] => DD
            [size] => 728x90
            [count] => 100
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [name] => DD
            [size] => 300x250
            [count] => 0
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [name] => DD
            [size] => 160x600
            [count] => 0
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [name] => DD
            [size] => 300x600
            [count] => 0
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [name] => DD
            [size] => 300x300
            [count] => 0
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [name] => DD
            [size] => 120x600
            [count] => 0
        )

    [28] => Array
        (
            [name] => DD
            [size] => 100x72
            [count] => 0
        )

    [29] => Array
        (
            [name] => DD
            [size] => 970x250
            [count] => 0
        )

    [30] => Array
        (
            [name] => DD
            [size] => 750x200
            [count] => 0
        )

    [31] => Array
        (
            [name] => DD
            [size] => 120x60
            [count] => 0
        )

    [32] => Array
        (
            [name] => DD
            [size] => 200x600
            [count] => 0
        )

)
```